# Spring + Spring Data JPA Configuration

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, persistence, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

currently I'm fooling around with a Spring setup. My goal is to use JPA to get access to a Websphere datasource using it's JNDI name. I'm using Spring Data JPA to make life easier for me and worked through some tutorials to get the basic idea.

Bad thing: none of those is talking about the Spring configuration for my JPA szenario + I never worked with JPA / JDBC before. 
So I hope you can help me out here. I got 2 configuration files:

applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="txManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

<bean id="eManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean"></bean>
```

Since i'm using the @Transactual annotion within my code, i'm using the annotation-driven tag for the txManager. I'm just not really sure what else i should configure for the txManager and what the sessionFactory tag is doing. Is there any documentation for all supported XML tags? Am I missing a importent tag for my szenario?

Same about eManager - not sure if thats right in any way.

persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="spring-jpa">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/myJNDI</jta-data-source>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Same thing here: don't really know what i'm doing. I know i need a persistence unit / provider. I know that many are using hibernate for this, but i would like to stay native and use pure JavaEE / Spring if possible. 
I'm just not sure how to configure that.
Currently my project is crashing, telling me: "JPA PersistenceProvider returned null"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to obtain the `EntityManagerFactory` from the JNDI via Spring's JNDI support:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="persistence/myPersistenceUnit" />

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.acme.repositories" />

<tx:jta-transactionManager />
```

This will cause the transaction manager being used from the application server as well. You can also try to setup a `JpaTransactionManager` and wire the `EntityManagerFactory` obtained from JNDI into it. You can pull even more configuration into your Spring config files if you only lookup the datasource through an `<jee:jndi-lookup />` namespace element and follow the further configuration instructions in the Spring Data JPA reference documentation. Nevertheless it's usually better to use the container resources you can actually get if you decide to use container resources at all.

Comment: but how do i know the jndi-name for the entityManagerFactory? and is the Persistence-Unit name element within the persistence.xml somehow linked to this? i don't understand whats actually happening here. the application makes a jndi-lookup to the server asking for a resource with the jndi-name "persistence/myP.." - how does it know its a EntityManager? How does this link to the persistence.xml configuration?

Comment: What you have configured is the JNDI name of the `DataSource`. The names are depending on the application server you're using so you need to look up this in your AS configuration/documentation.
The `repositories` element expects to find a bean called `entityManagerFactory` which you lookup through the `jndi-lookup` element. For more detailled documentation regarding the `jee` namespace have a look at the [reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-jee).

Comment: now i configured the server (WebSphere) to use openJPA as an default persistence provider. the doc sais websphere will use the default persistence provider if the <provider> element within persistence.xml is blank.but there seems to be no way to configure a JNDI name for the default provider, so what should i enter for the jndi-name of the eneityManagerFactory? second problem: i'm now getting a missing ExceptionTranslator error. i looked it up and it seems like i should declare a bean for it which implements  the JPADialect. However:seems like spring has no OpenJPA class for that. what to do?

Comment: quit the second problem, i just found org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect and the error has gone. Still: i'm getting errors because i can't provide a JNDI name to the default provider.

Comment: It's got to be documented somewhere in the WebSphere world, sorry I can't help you any further than that…

Comment: hmm well i guess i got to stumble around for it. thanks anyways, your help saved me alot of try & error

Comment: Hmm, but just to make sure: the PersistenceProvider JNDI is NOT the same as the DataSource JNDI, right?

Answer (score 3):

I just started working with Spring, jpa mysql etc... and I might be able to help you out.
I'll show you the way that I have my configuration right know.

I'm using hibernate by the way for my database connection, I've never did it without so no help from me there :)

My configuration:

Spring-config.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.MYPACKAGE"/> 
<!-- To find all your controllers -->

<tx:annotation-driven/> 
<!-- This will pickup all your @Transactional annotations-->

<import resource="../database/DataSource.xml"/>
<import resource="../database/Hibernate.xml"/>
<!-- These are my database config files-->
```

Datasource.xml:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DATABASENAME"/>
    <property name="username" value="USERNAME"/>
    <property name="password" value="PASSWORD"/>
</bean>
```

Hibernate.xml:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I left out the standard xml text that you need to include at the top of your .xml files, but I trust you to work that out yourself ;)

This setup works for me and I hope it can help you out!
If you have any question regarding this post please let me know!

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately you're describeing a JDBC + Hibernate setup which differs alot from what I'm trying to do. But atleast your answer showed me that the tx:annotation-driven should be way enough for my setup, so thanks for that!

Answer (score 2):

for those using JBoss, the jndi names can be set in persistence.xml properties like this:

```
    <persistence-unit name="punit" transaction-type="JTA">

      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <jta-data-source>java:/myDS/jta-data-source>

      <class>com.company.model.Document</class>
      <class>com.company.model.DocumentIndividual</class>

      <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
        <!-- <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/> -->
        <property name="javax.persistence.logging.level" value="INFO" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="jboss.entity.manager.jndi.name" value="java:/my_em"/>
        <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:/my_emf"/>
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

as described in [here](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/reference/build/reference/en/html/entityconfig.html) section 4.4.2